# upload pytest json report to logstash

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, pytest, elastic-stack

I have json file for test results generated by pytest using pytest-json pluggin. So each json file contains test results of one test run. I want to upload this single json file into elasticsearch through logstash. But when I try it with the below logstash conf file, it is splitting the json file and posting as multiple docs in elasticsearch where I expect it to be uploaded as only one doc. Because of this split my results data is all distributed in multiple docs and getting corrupted.

logstash conf:

```
    input {

        file {

                start_position => "beginning"

                path => "home/report.json"

                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"

        }
}
filter {

        json {

                source => "message"

        }

}
output {

        elasticsearch {

                hosts => "http://localhost:9200"

                index => "demo_ds"

        }
}
```

Comment: What does your `report.json` file looks like? Do you have multiple lines? Each line will be trated as a single document by logstash.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your file input with a multiline codec

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/user/report.json"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => multiline { pattern => "^Spalanzani" negate => true what => "previous" auto_flush_interval => 2 }
    }
}
```

The codec takes every line that does not match the regular expression ^Spalanzani (i.e., it takes every line) and combines them into one event. The auto_flush_interval is required because otherwise it will wait forever for a line that does match ^Spalanzani.

Note that a file input only accepts absolute paths.